# actionbarsherlock with multiple fragments under a single tab

Tags: android, tabs, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

I created my Sherlock fragment activity and implemented tabs:

```
public class Home extends SherlockFragmentActivity
{
ActionBar actionBar;
TabHost myTabHost;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    actionBar=getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    ActionBar.Tab tab1= actionBar.newTab();
    ActionBar.Tab tab2= actionBar.newTab();
    //ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionBar.newTab();
    tab1.setText("Contacts");
    tab2.setText("Inbox");
//  tab3.setText("Outbox");
    tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
    tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
    actionBar.addTab(tab1, true);
    actionBar.addTab(tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(tab3);
}
```

And this is my tab change listener:

```
private class MyTabListener implements TabListener
{

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if(tab.getPosition()==0)
        {
            FragmentA frag = new FragmentA ();
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content, frag );
        }
        else
        {
            FragmentB frag = new FragmentB ();
            ft.replace(android.R.id.content,frag );
        }
    }
```

And this is my FragmentA:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment 
{
    TextView textView;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);
}
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

Here under my first tab, there is a list that is displaying. When I click any one of the list items, I need to load another fragment under the same activity. And when back is pressed, the old fragment needs to be loaded under the same tab.

Is this possible in actionbarsherlock tabs? If so, how do I do this?

Comment: please give me some hints.......

Comment: could you precise your question? What is not working? Its possible to have "Master-Detail-Fragments" like its described on the android developers side (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html#Fragments).